# String manipulation - Can this be made better?

Tags: c#, string

Right now we're hand rolling logins and one of the requirements is to have the login page 
notify the user which module they're going to login to. Now the only thing I have to work 
with that has the URL they're going to land on is in a query string such as this:

```
Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"]
```

With a value like this:

```
~/moduleFolder/SpecificPage.aspx
```

Now this is the method that I created that can break that URL up by the forward slash,
take that segment seperate the words, capitalize the first word, remove the first slash,
and assign it back to the label for display. An example of the code is below:

```
string incomingName = Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"].ToString();
int first = incomingName.IndexOf(@"/");
int last = incomingName.LastIndexOf(@"/");
string tempName = incomingName.Substring(first, last - first);
string seperatedName = Regex.Replace(tempName, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
string upperCased = seperatedName.Replace("/", "");
string portalName = char.ToUpper(upperCased[0]) + upperCased.Substring(1);
lblPortalName.Text = portalName;
```

Is there a cleaner or better way to write this code with out having so many different instances of a new string?

Comment: Could use the string builder class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string url = "~/moduleFolder/SpecificPage.aspx";
string moduleFolder = url.Split('/')[1];
string separatedName = Regex.Replace(moduleFolder, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
string portalName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(separatedName);
```

Comment: The names of the strings make a lot more sense than what I made up.

Comment: @Chris: made it one line shorter by inlining the `CurrentCulture` stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the cleaner way would be like this:

```
private static string GetMiddleSegment(string URL)
{
    // you should probably use a library function for this kind of thing

    int first = URL.IndexOf(@"/");
    int last = URL.LastIndexOf(@"/");
    return URL.Substring(first + 1, last - first - 1); // this is correct, right?
}

private static string SeparateWords(string camelCase)
{
    return Regex.Replace(camelCase, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
}

private static string Uppercase(string name)
{
    return char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
}

// ...

string incomingURL = Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"].ToString();
string nameSegment = GetMiddleSegment(incomingURL);
string displayName = Uppercase(SeparateWords(nameSegment));
lblPortalName.Text = displayName;
```

You'll notice that my code doesn't create less string instances.  That's because there's absolutely no way that the amount of string instances created here has anything to do with your performance when serving a request.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't change it. At best you'll save a few lines of code, but as it is, this code is probably more readable since this allows for descriptive names of the string at each step of manipulation.

Though you might look into library url functions instead of implementing your own.

Comment: Making this into a helper based out of a library is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the code that gets the part between the first and second /s like this:

```
var tempName = incomingName.Split('/').Last();
```

This is quite terser and IMO no harder to understand. Plus, it saves you the trouble of doing

```
string upperCased = seperatedName.Replace("/", "");
```

so the end result is 3 lines shorter without loss of readability.

**Edit:**

Simplified the `Split` call after the OP's comment that there will only be two slashes. The `.Last()` call can of course be substituted with `[1]`, although personally I prefer the way `.Last()` reads. It conveys intent more clearly than a magic number, especially if you are not the author of the code.

Comment: His code gets the part between the first and the last '/', not necessarily the first and the second '/'.  Of course, maybe in his case there's no difference.

Comment: @mquander: true. But it looks like the OP's code would run together the parts separated by slashes, so maybe he's assuming only 2 slashes anyway?

Comment: var tempName = incomingName.Split('/')[1];

Comment: In the environment that I'm working in, we're only going to be working in two layers. The root and secondary folder. So we'll always be working with a slash folder slash page format.

Answer (score 0):

Based on *RedFilter's regular expression* you could created simple **extension methods** like:

```
private static string UrlModuleName(this string url)
{
    return Regex.Replace(url.Split('/')[1], "([a-z])([A-Z])",
                         "$1 $2").ToTitleCaseInvariant();
}
private static string ToTitleCaseInvariant(this string input)
{
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input);
}
```

*This is a good idea to get it simple*.